# Compilation issue with existential types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, existential-type, heterogeneous, heterogeneous-array

I've written a simple typeclass `Shape`:

```hs
class Shape a where
  draw   :: a -> IO ()
  move   :: (Double,Double) -> a -> a
  area   :: a -> Double
  circum :: a -> Double
```

I also have concrete types `Circle`, `Rect` and `Triangle` that instantiate this typeclass like so:

```hs
data Circle = Circle Point Double deriving (Show)

instance Shape Circle where
  draw       (Circle centre radius) = putStrLn $ "Circle [" ++ show centre ++ ", " ++ show radius ++ "]"
  move (x,y) (Circle centre radius) = Circle (movePoint x y centre) radius
  area   (Circle _ r) = r ^ 2 * pi
  circum (Circle _ r) = 2 * r * pi

movePoint :: Double -> Double -> Point -> Point
movePoint x y (Point x_a y_a) = Point (x_a + x) (y_a + y)
```

In order to work with heterogenous lists containing instances of the concrete types `Circle`, `Rect` and `Triangle` I followed [the haskell wiki tutorial on heterogenous collections](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections#Existential_types) and implemented an existential data type `ShapeType` like so:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data ShapeType = forall a . Shape a => MkShape a
```

I let `ShapeType`instantiate the `Shape` type class:

```hs
instance Shape ShapeType where
  area     (MkShape s) = area s
  circum   (MkShape s) = circum s
  draw     (MkShape s) = draw s
  move (x,y) (MkShape s) =  move (x,y) s  -- this does not compile
```

Now I can use this in code like follows:

```hs
rect = Rect (Point 0 0) (Point 5 4)
circle = Circle (Point 4 5) 4
triangle = Triangle (Point 0 0) (Point 4 0) (Point 4 3)

shapes :: [ShapeType]
shapes = [MkShape rect, MkShape circle, MkShape triangle]

main = do
  print $ map area shapes
  print $ map circum shapes
  mapM_ draw shapes
```

Unfortunately this only compiles if I ommit the line

`move (x,y) (MkShape s) =  move (x,y) s`

Otherwise I get the following compilation error:

```
error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `ShapeType' with actual type `a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          MkShape :: forall a. Shape a => a -> ShapeType,
        in an equation for `move'
        at C:\\workspace\FPvsOO\src\Lib.hs:102:15-23
    * In the expression: move (x, y) s
      In an equation for `move': move (x, y) (MkShape s) = move (x, y) s
      In the instance declaration for `Shape ShapeType'
    * Relevant bindings include
        s :: a (bound at C:\\workspace\FPvsOO\src\Lib.hs:102:23)
```

This doesn't make sense to me, as "extracting" the `s` by pattern matching for usage in the delegating calls works fine in the other three cases.

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

**Update**

With this simple fix the code now works as expected:

```hs
instance Shape ShapeType where
  area     (MkShape s) = area s
  circum   (MkShape s) = circum s
  draw     (MkShape s) = draw s
  move vec (MkShape s) = MkShape (move vec s)
```

Comment: A good alternative to existentials here is a record of functions: `data S = S { draw ∷ IO (), move ∷ (Double, Double) → S, … }`. Shapes are defined as structural compositions of behaviour rather than nominal types in a typeclass: `circle c r = S { draw = putStrLn "Circle" …, move = \(x, y) → circle (movePoint x y c) r, … }`. The closure capturing fields like `c` & `r` is *already* existential, but you can also explicitly hide fields existentially *without* a typeclass: `data S where { S ∷ ∀ s. { fields ∷ s, draw ∷ s → IO (), move ∷ (Double, Double) → s → s, … } → S }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a constructor. You need

```
move v (MkShape s) = MkShape $ move v s
```

I'm not so convinced your approach here is really best; existential types tend to just gum up the works in this sort of situation. You should at least consider a plain old sum type. Existentials are invaluable for some purposes, but in other contexts they're actively harmful.

Comment: Thanks a ton! What a stupid error...
I somehow got confused by the compiler message...

Comment: Thanks also for your comment on better using a simple sum type.

Comment: When are existential types invaluable?

Comment: @is7s, my latest use involves deamortization of lazy binomial queues represented using a non-regular datatype. More interesting uses include type-aligned sequences, some representations of free `Applicative` functors, the traversal capturing mechanisms in `lens` and `bifunctors`, and the `Coyoneda` type. I don't have any rules of thumb for when existential types are a good idea; they just pop up from time to time.